# Eclipse - Object has no attribute. AttributeError

Tags: eclipse

I am getting an Attribute error on the main(). Can someone please help me out?
This is my class:

import math

class Cylinder2():

```
    def __init__(self, cylRadius = 1, cylHeight = 1):
        self.__radius = cylRadius
        self.__height = cylHeight
    def getPerimeter(self):
        return (2 * math.pi * self.__radius)
    def getEndArea(self):
        return (math.pi * (self.__radius ** 2))
    def getSideArea(self):
        return (2 * (math.pi * (self.__radius * (self.__height))))
    def getSurfaceArea(self):
        return (2 * (math.pi * (self.__radius) * (self.__height + self.__radius)))
    def getVolume(self):
        return (math.pi * (self.__radius ** 2) * self.__height)
    def setRadius(self, r):
        self.__radius = r
    def setHeight(self, h):
        self.__height = h
    def getRadius(self):
        return self.__radius
    def getHeight(self):
        return self.__height
```

This is the main():

from CylinderModule2 import *

def main():

```
    bottle = Cylinder2(4, 8)

    bottle.setRadius(2)   
    bottle.setHeight(4)
    print("The radius and height of the bottle are: ", bottle.__radius, " and ", bottle.__height)
    print("The perimeter of the bottle end circle is", ("%.2f" % bottle.getPerimeter()))
    print("The end circle area of the bottle is ", ("%.2f" % bottle.getEndArea()))
    print("The side area of the bottle is ", ("%.2f" % bottle.getSideArea()))
    print("The total surface of the bottle is ", ("%.2f" % bottle.getSurfaceArea()))
    print("The volume of the bottle is ", ("%.2f" % bottle.getVolume()))
```

main()

This is the error I get:
print("The radius and height of the bottle are: ", bottle._*radius, " and ", bottle.*_height)
AttributeError: 'Cylinder2' object has no attribute '__radius'

Answer (score 1):

`bottle.__radius` and `bottle.__height` are what can loosely be described as private variables (even though they are not really, you can read about what I mean here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references )
"private" variables can not be directly accessed from outside of the class. In Python, they are denoted by using two underscores (as in __radius).

So what you want to do is using the getters, which are `bottle.getRadius()` and `bottle.getHeight()` instead.